# How can I make PS script to create Hyper-V VM set administrator password for VM?

Tags: hyper-v, powershell, scvmm

When I create a VM in Virtual Machine Manager (VMM) I have an option to set a local administrator password for it. But when I use the "View Script" feature on the last screen of the wizard, I get a PowerShell script that creates a VM without setting a password.

How can I make the PowerShell script set the password for the local administrator account for the VM it creates?

Comment: maybe use dism against the offlined vhd file and inject a script into the system runonce regkeys once it boots up it may set the pw.  don't know can try at the moment. But I thought it was a good question!!

Comment: actually I think you can apply an unattended.xml file against an offline image!

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have VMV, at the [MS Script Guiding](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963748.aspx) may help. It shows Powershell scripts which has a number of variables, one being the admin password one you want. I would assume the script VMM is creating is similar to these.